# QDialog module error in Maya 2017

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, maya

My question is about a QDialog module error I got in Maya 2017.

I am using Maya 2017 to follow a PyQt for Maya course that is demo-ed in Maya 2015. I installed Qt.py hoping to simplify the code and avoid the confusing between PyQt4 vs PyQt5 or PySide vs PySide2.

So, when I do

```
print Qt
```

I get the following in Script Editor so assume everything is good.

```
<module 'Qt' from 'C:/Users/chuang/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\Qt.pyc'>
```

However, when I follow a demo that successfully pulls up an empty window by the below in Maya 2015:

```
import Qt.QtCore as qc
import Qt.QtGui as qg
dialog = qg.QDialog()
dialog.show()
```

I did the same in Maya 2017 and got the error message below:

```
# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 4: 'module' object has no attribute 'QDialog' #
```

Do I miss something here (hopefully not a typo :) )?

The only way I can get it to work in Maya 2017 is if I do:

```
import Qt.QtWidgets as qw
import Qt.QtCore as qc
import Qt.QtGui as qg

dialog = qw.QDialog()
dialog.show()
```

But I don't understand why it works.

Comment: Looks like there was an upgrade from Qt4 to Qt5. Nothing you can do about that besides keep up with the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the upgrade of Qt4 to Qt5 since Maya 2017, and that's why I installed the Qt.py as a layering hoping to be able to use any PyQt library.

Seems like QDialog is under QtWidgets in PyQt5 and that probably explains why it didn't work for me try to call it via QtGui.
Apparently, it worked in Maya 2015 (PyQt4) via QtGui.

Answer (score 1):

In Maya 2017 and Maya 2018, a bunch of stuff was taken out from `QtGui` module and instead placed in the new `QtWidgets` module. So you're right, it works via `QtWidgets` now.

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qw
import PySide2.QtCore as qc
import PySide2.QtGui as qg

dialog = qw.QDialog()
dialog.show()
```

Read cool post about `PySide2` by Fredrik Averpil: [Dealing with Maya 2017 and PySide2](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/25/dealing-with-maya-2017-and-pyside2/).

Comment: ah.. I see. Thanks so much Andy. Will read Fredrik's post for sure. 

cheers.